# Listview not exporting columns to excel

Tags: c#, excel, listview, export

I'm trying to export a listview to an excel file. The information in the listview is exported successfully, but the columns are not. Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
int i = 1;
int i2 = 1;
int x = 1;
int x2 = 1;
foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns)
{
    ws.Cells[x2, x] = ch.Text;
    x++;
}

foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
{
    i = 1;
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
    {
        ws.Cells[i2, i] = lvs.Text;
        ws.Cells.Select();
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        i++;
    }
    i2++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by setting `i2 = 2` instead of `i2 = 1`? May be, 2nd part is overwriting the columnheader because of `i2 = 1`.